# How can I hide a TextView based on the instance of the common Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am learning android development, I tried to make a simple tour guide app.

I used two different classes and corresponding adapters to achieve this. The adapter concerning to the question has an `ImageView` and two `TextView`s.

One of them is on top of the image and the other is below the image.

This is how it looks

[image: The layout of first instance of the fragment]

The layout of first instance of the fragment

Then I reuse the `Fragment` with only the `ImageView` being present.

Somehow a portion of the `TextView` in the first instance is creeping into this instance. Like in this image

[image: The blue portion is the textview background color]

The blue portion is the textview background color

Now the code

**Here is the XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e2f1f8"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <FrameLayout

            android:id="@+id/image_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Place_image_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:foreground="@drawable/gradient"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/edpl_min" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/place_text_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="@string/town_name"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#42a5f5">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/description"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is the custom class for this layout:**

```
package com.example.sharathprakash.tourguide;

/**
 * Created by Sharath Prakash on 10/15/2017.
 */

public class Info {
    private String mplacename;
    private int mImageResource;
    private String mdescription;
    private static final int NO_TEXT_PROVIDED = -1;


    public Info(String placename, String description, int imageresource) {
        mplacename = placename;
        mdescription = description;
        mImageResource = imageresource;

    }

    public Info(int imageresource, String placename) {
        mImageResource = imageresource;
        mplacename = placename;

    }

    public String getplacename() {

        return mplacename;
    }

    public String getdescription() {
        return mdescription;
    }

    /* public boolean hasText(){
         return mImageResource != NO_TEXT_PROVIDED;
     }*/
    public int getImageResource() {
        return mImageResource;
    }
}
```

**Here is the adapter:**

```
package com.example.sharathprakash.tourguide;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Sharath Prakash on 10/15/2017.
 */

public class InfoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Info> {
    public InfoAdapter(Activity Context, ArrayList<Info> inf) {
        super(Context, 0, inf);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;

        if (listItemView == null) {

            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(

                    R.layout.info_fragment_layout, parent, false);

        }
        Info currentnumber = getItem(position);
        TextView placetextview = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.place_text_view);
        TextView descriptiontextview = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        ImageView Placeimageview = (ImageView) 
        listItemView.findViewById(R.id.Place_image_view);
        placetextview.setText(currentnumber.getplacename());
        descriptiontextview.setText(currentnumber.getdescription());
        Placeimageview.setImageResource(currentnumber.getImageResource());
        return listItemView;
    }

}
```

My question is how can I hide this `TextView` in the second image?

Also any way to add a drop shadow to the `ImageView`s will be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the TextView doing:

```
descriptiontextview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

When you want it to be hidden.

And to show it again:

```
descriptiontextview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Also you could have it hidden by default setting this attribute in the TextView .xml:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, one more thing how can i get the app to know which fragment instance it is in? I mean i need the text view for the first instance and don't need it for the second instance

Comment: Do you want to do scroll or something like that, knowing which fragment is shown? This is a problem because more than one fragment could be shown at the same time

Comment: Post another question and let me know

Comment: Yes, sir the second instance need to be scrollable. I need to get rid of that blue bar which is the leftover of the descriptiontextview from the first instance.